# WooCommerce REST API Get User Timezone

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My goal is to pull a list of orders using a date range, using the WooCommerce REST API. Here is my query:

https://1106-7916.el-alt.com/wp-json/wc/v2/orders?after=2017-03-30T14:21:00Z&before=2017-03-30T14:23:00Z&per_page=50&page=1&consumer_key=C&consumer_secret=X

It appears the after and before must be converted to the user's timezone, since UTC is too far ahead. I want to convert the after and before date to the user's timezone. How do I get the WooCommerce website timezone, using the REST API?

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#order-properties

Here is the timezone field in WordPress:

[image]

Comment: Have you solved it?